# Castle Windsor constructor injection in WPF ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, castle-windsor

I am trying to avoid the anti-pattern of Container.Resolve(). How do I change the following to use contructor injection?

Installers.cs

```
 public void Install(Castle.Windsor.IWindsorContainer container, 
                            Castle.MicroKernel.SubSystems.Configuration.IConfigurationStore store)
        {

            container.AddFacility<TypedFactoryFacility>();

            container

             .Register(Component.For<IData>()
                .ImplementedBy<Data>().LifeStyle.Singleton)



        }
```

BootStrapper.cs

```
public class Bootstrapper
    {
        private static volatile IWindsorContainer _theWindsorContainer;
        private static object syncRoot = new Object();

        public static IWindsorContainer Container
        {
            get
            {
                if (_theWindsorContainer == null)
                {
                    lock (syncRoot)
                    {
                        if (_theWindsorContainer == null)
                        {
                            _theWindsorContainer = new WindsorContainer().Install(FromAssembly.This());
                        }
                    }
                }

                return _theWindsorContainer;
            }
        }
    }
```

OViewModel.cs

```
public IData ThisData {get;set;}

public OViewModel()
{

  ThisData= Bootstrapper.Container.Resolve<IData>(); 
  InitializeComponent(); 
}
```

How do I use Windsor Castle constructor injection to initialize the viewmodel and do constructor injection? Either InitializeComponentdoesn't get called or ThisData is null.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I [wrote an article](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2011/10/01/wpf-and-inversion-of-control.aspx) a few years ago about integrating Castle Windsor into WPF to achieve DI in your view models.  It might be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the particulars of Castle Windsor, but typically you would structure your OViewModel like this:

```
public class OViewModel
{
  public IData ThisData { get; set; } //private set??

  public OViewModel(IData _thisData)
  {
    ThisData = _thisData;
    InitializeComponent();
  }
}
```

That would be constructor injection.  You can search for the term parameter injection for other ways of getting it done.

But basically the when an OViewModel is resolved by the container, it knows how to resolve an IData and will automatically resolve it for you.

Of course, this just backs things up -- whatever is creating the OViewModel needs to use container.Resolve and you don't want to do that.  So you'll probably inject the view model (or an interface of it) (or a factory object) to that parent object.  And so on back up the chain until you have single object that is the root of your application that you need to resolve from the container to get everything started.

Hopefully someone with more knowledge of the particulars of Castle Windsor can give you more details.